# Kubuntu terminal setting depending on display

Tags: linux, console, fonts, multi-monitor

I am running Kubuntu on dual screen configuration. Both displays have the same resolutions (FullHD) but the trick is that one is significantly smaller than the other (24 inch monitor vs. 15 inch laptop) so font size differs a lot. Usually it isn't a problem but using a console is pretty painful sometimes.

Since Kubuntu is able to determine different task managers per screen, is it possible to automate profile settings change so that font-size is modified depending on the display?